# Mean time of absorption on a cube

Tags: probability, markov-process

A spider and a bug are located on the opposite corners of a regular cube. At each time instant they are allowed to move only along the edges of the cube. Each movement along an edge is equally likely. Calculate the mean time when they meet.

In this problem I tried to solve through markov process as there are 4 states. However, according to me they never meet if they are in opposite diagonal. So is the mean time will be infinite? Can some body comment in this regards?

Comment: If they are at opposite ends of a particular edge and both choose that edge then presumably they meet in the middle of that edge (or do you assume they teleport?)

Comment: @Henry But they have started from diagonal opposite so I guess they wont meet that my assumption

Comment: If they are on opposite diagonals then they start three edges apart.  After one step each they are either one edge apart or three edges apart.  Then during the second step they can meet halfway along an edge, or take another full step and be either one edge apart or three edges apart.  The probabilities are not equal, but in this interpretation  the expected time to meet is finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the bug is too dull to realize that it is running into the spider, and that the spider's belly is full so it really doesn't care whether it can eat this bug. However, given their behavior, we can frame equations thus.

When they take the first step, although each has $3$ possibilities, so $9$ possibilities in all, a little thought would show that due to symmetry, it is enough to consider that the bug takes some particular step, and the spider has $3$ choices.

Denoting the initial position with a distance of $3$  between them by *a*, positions  with a distance of $1$ between them as *b*, with one step taken by each, we get the equation

$a = 1 + \frac13\cdot a + \frac23\cdot b$

[With $1$ set of moves, either we return to initial state with probability $\frac13$, or move ahead $2$ steps with probability $\frac23$]

All we need to do now is to frame the equation after the second set of moves, and solve. [Remember that here you'll need to consider $9$ possibilities ]

> $b = 1 +\frac29\cdot a + \frac 69\cdot b$